# Angular material table footer - alignment issue

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

Having an issues with the footer alignment in an angular material table. Seemingly inexplicable.

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, two of the footer columns flatly refuse to align correctly. I have currently forced them all to align left in the html but as you see, the 'edit' column footer and the 'mon' column footer remain out of whack.

Column definitions are defined as:

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'edit', 'delete', 'project', 'site', 'location', 
    'shift', 'workpack', 'description', 'mon', 'tue', 
    'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun', 'total'
  ];

  dataSource = this.rows;
```

template:

```
<!---- header ----->
<div class="wrap">

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="rows" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="edit">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Edit </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></td>
      <th mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> - </th>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></td>
      <th mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> - </th>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="project">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Project </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.project}} </td>
      <th mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> - </th>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="site">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Site </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.site}} </td>
      <th mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> - </th>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.location}} </td>
      <th mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> - </th>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="shift">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Shift </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.shift}} </td>
      <th mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> - </th>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="workpack">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Workpack </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.workpack}} </td>
      <th mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> - </th>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.description}} </td>
      <th mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> - </th>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="mon">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Mon</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.mon}} </td>
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> {{totals[6]}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="tue">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Tue</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.tue}} </td>
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> {{ totals[5] }} </td>

    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="wed">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Wed</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.wed}} </td>
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> {{ totals[4] }} </td>

    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="thu">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Thu</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.thu}} </td>
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> {{ totals[3] }} </td>

    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="fri">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Frid</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.fri}} </td>
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> {{ totals[2] }} </td>

    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="sat">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Sat</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.sat}} </td>
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> {{ totals[1] }} </td>

    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="sun">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Sun</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.sun}} </td>
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> {{ totals[0] }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="total">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Total</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.total}} </td>
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="text-align: left"> {{ grandTotal }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

and CSS

```
.wrap {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 90%;
}

.mat-raised-button{
  margin-right: 20px;
}

mat-form-field {
  margin-right: 12px
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

These columns remain misaligned regardless of what I change, including changing the displayed footer columns to purely be the days of the week with actual totals.

Any assistance would be appreciated as I'm tearing my hair out on this one!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the problem: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11232

I was able to recreate your issue using a single component. I used your template and CSS. Here is the component definition:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

interface RowDef {
  edit: boolean;
  delete: boolean;
  project: string;
  site: string;
  location: string;
  shift: string;
  workpack: string;
  description: string;
  mon: number;
  tue: number;
  wed: number;
  thu: number;
  fri: number;
  sat: number;
  sun: number;
  total: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-table-align",
  templateUrl: "./table-align.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./table-align.component.css"],
})
export class TableAlignComponent implements OnInit {
  rows: RowDef[] = [
    {
      edit: true,
      delete: true,
      project: "Project",
      site: "MySite",
      location: "Bulgaria",
      shift: "first",
      workpack: "2002",
      description: "nadda",
      mon: 0,
      tue: 0,
      wed: 0,
      thu: 0,
      fri: 0,
      sat: 0,
      sun: 0,
      total: 0,
    },
  ];

  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    "edit",
    "delete",
    "project",
    "site",
    "location",
    "shift",
    "workpack",
    "description",
    "mon",
    "tue",
    "wed",
    "thu",
    "fri",
    "sat",
    "sun",
    "total",
  ];

  totals: number[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  grandTotal: number;

  dataSource = this.rows;

  constructor() {
    this.grandTotal = this.totals.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

The attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEZCm.png) shows that the CSS appears to be applied to different columns in the header and footer resulting in what you see.

I have the same issue in one of my apps. I'm going to try overriding the CSS per 11232 to see if that helps.